# Beeper for lost FPV drone

Tags: piezo-buzzer, quad-copter, drone

I am not an expert in electronics, just the very basics so please bear with me.

I am trying to create beeper alarm for my FPV drone that will activate when it crashes or no movement for certain period.

There are some important requirements.

1. The device should turn on when external power source (Quad LiPo) is connected.
2. Alarm will go off, if the power source is removed (separate switch to turn it off) or if no movement is detected for 30 sec.

i don't know how to put this together, like do i have to program a micro controller or is there any other way?

I live in India, where drone parts so hard to find. Therefore i need this DIY.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: This is a rudimentary of what i have in mind]

Comment: Why not just have it producing a beep pulse every second irrespective of anything else. Battery power requirement s will be low and you won't need to fit an accelerometer and "other stuff". Justify why this cannot be done with a simple battery powered bleeper that would last for weeks if you didn't deactivate it.

Comment: @brhans - i am thinking of using zenor diode and there is a secondary lipo 1s 3.7v. Andy aka - beeping continuously is annoying (i use headphones), also i have place another beeper within Flight controller for low voltage alarm.

Comment: not an electronic solution, but, in terms of requirements...  "no movement for 30 seconds" might need to be modified, lest you want to hover and beep... if you can even hover with no "movement", I dunno, I don't have a quadcopter.  Just something to think about for your "other stuff" block :)

Comment: @CapnJJ To be honest i am trying to replicate this product with added features [link](http://www.nichemall.net/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50)